# sudo: pip3: command not found - in centos 7

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I try to install pysftp==0.2.8 in centos 7 for odoo 12 with the command

sudo pip3 install pysftp==0.2.8

sudo: pip3: command not found   --- this  error appeared

and try with the command   pip3 install pysftp==0.2.8

-bash: pip3: command not found  --- appeared

When I locate pip3

/opt/odoo12/venv/bin/pip3

/opt/odoo12/venv/bin/pip3.6

/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/bin/pip3

/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/bin/pip3.6

I want to install the pysftp==0.2.8 package using pip3

Please help me to resolve this issue

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your pip executable is not in your PATH, which is why the shell is not finding it when you try to run it.

You *could* modify the PATH variable directly to include that bin directory.

You *could* call pip3 directly using the absolute path of the executable, since you obviously know where to find it.

But, it appears from the paths you've provided that you're using virtual environments for your Python installation. If that's the case, you need to activate the venv before it's executables will be available to you. Activating a venv modifies the PATH correctly for you.

```
source /opt/odoo12/venv/bin/activate
```

then your pip3 command should work.

Comment: Sorry, I can't get you. How to activate the venv. which file will modify and where I can add the path

Comment: I told you how to activate the venv. I gave you the command. Sounds like you need to spend some time learning how your python install works before you ask questions. Google is your friend.